# Rails 4 before_save build & update ActiveRecords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, before-save, after-create

On Rails 4, I am using Devise login. On first sign_in user gets directed to new_profile_path(@user) or profile_path(@profile = @user.profile_id). I am building the Profile ActiveRecord during User Registration. I'd like to pass the profile.id that is created during registration back to the User ActiveRecord before_save.

I am able to test with success "after_create", the build is working fine. Then "before_save" I'm able to get it to work by hard-coding a profile_id (see working code below). However, I cannot figure out after an entire day on the proper method to pass profile_id. I obviously do not want a hard-coded value. Here is my model code.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

 has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy, autosave: true
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

 after_create :build_profile

 before_save :set_profile_id




 def build_profile
    Profile.create(user: self) # Associations must be defined correctly for this syntax, avoids using ID's directly.

  end

 def set_profile_id
    self.profile_id = 30 # Hard-coding tested and works. Profile built with user_id = user.id and user.profile_id = 30
 end

end



class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  #validates :username, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]*\z/, message: "deve contar apenas letras e números" }
  #validates :firstname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}
  #validates :lastname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}
  #validates :gender, presence: true, inclusion: %w(m f)
  #validates :birthday, presence: true

  has_many :offers, dependent: :delete_all

  before_save :set_address


  geocoded_by :address               # can also be an IP address

  def address
    address = "#{street_address}, #{city}, #{state}, #{zipcode}"
  end
  after_validation :geocode          # auto-fetch coordinates

  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
  after_validation :reverse_geocode  # auto-fetch address


  has_attached_file :logo_image, :styles => { :medium => "250x250>", :small => "175x175>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

  # Validate content type
  validates_attachment_content_type :logo_image, :content_type => /\Aimage/
  # Validate filename
  validates_attachment_file_name :logo_image, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/, /JPG?\Z/]

  validates_attachment_size :logo_image, :less_than => 2.megabytes
  #validates_attachment_presence :avatar
  # Explicitly do not validate
  #do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :avatar


  # This may not be necessary anymore. With 'def address' above. Keeping for now as reference
  def set_address
    self.address = "#{street_address}, #{city}, #{state}, #{zipcode}"
  end



end



class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController



  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    build_resource({})
    @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
    if @validatable
      @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
    end
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

   resource_saved = resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_saved
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     else
       set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
       expire_data_after_sign_in!
       respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     end
   else
     clean_up_passwords resource
     @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
     if @validatable
       @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
     end
     respond_with resource
   end
 end


  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_id, :profile_id)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :user_id, :profile_id)
  end


end





class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@profiles) do |profile, marker|
        marker.lat profile.latitude
        marker.lng profile.longitude
        marker.infowindow profile.address
    end
  end

  def address 
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:address])
    Geocode.search("@profile")
  end 

  def show
    @profiles = Profile.all
    @offers = Offer.where(user_id: current_user.id) 
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@profiles) do |profile, marker|
        marker.lat profile.latitude
        marker.lng profile.longitude
        marker.infowindow profile.address
    end

  end

  def new
    @user = current_user   # added to solve for session re-direct on sign-in
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
    #@user.profile_id = @profile.id  # added to solve for session re-direct on sign-in
    if @profile.save

      flash[:notice] = "Profile has been created."

      redirect_to @profile
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Profile has not been created."

      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@profiles) do |profile, marker|
        marker.lat profile.latitude
        marker.lng profile.longitude
        marker.infowindow profile.address
      end  

  end

  def update
    if @profile.update(profile_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Profile has been updated."
      redirect_to @profile
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Profile has not been updated."
      render "edit"
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @profile.destroy

    flash[:notice] = "Profile has been destroyed."

    redirect_to profiles_path
  end




  private

    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:id, :firstname, :lastname, :company, :website, :street_address, :city, :state, :zipcode, :phone, :logo_image, :address, :latitude, :longitude, :user_id, :user_email_id)
    end

    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      flash[:alert] = "The profile you were looking for could not be found."
      redirect_to profiles_path
    end

end
```

Comment: I believe you already know that before saving there is no ID, since the DB Engine provides it, unless you don't use autonumber. The only way to get it's value, is through an after_create callback. But again, you're seeing this all wrong... on your after_create method, you could use direct association: `self.profile.create(...)`, and you can let ActiveRecord worry about the ids...

Comment: Thank you. Yes. Agree, approaching this wrong. I'm taking a step back and solving for the redirect in the profiles.user_id provided by ActiveRecord